Accidentally dropped information_schema postgres
I accidentally ran and committed drop schema information_schema cascade on postgres 15.4 as a DBA.
How to recreate the said schema?


Do you need it? 2) Do you have another database that still has it? 3) If the answer to 2) is yes you could try pg_dump -d  otherdb_name -n information_schema -U postgres -f info_sch.sql and then psql -d db_name -U postgres -f info_sch.sql. You want to make sure the other db is the same major version as the one you want to restore to as the information_schema contains views over the Postgres system catalogs and they can change between major versions.


Before anything else, make a backup of your database!

@AdrianKlaver 1. yes it's required in some major ways. 2. sorry no backup

You don't need  a backup just another database in the cluster. If one does not exist then create a 'dummy' data e.g. CREATE DATABASE dummy_db and then use the pg_dump command I provided previously against that database. Per Frank Heikens
, make sure you do a backup of your current database before making any changes.

@AdrianKlaver Is that the same as https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_15_4/src/backend/catalog/information_schema.sql ?

Yes it is the same assuming you use the correct the Postgres version.

Create a new database, take a pg_dump of the database where you dropped information_schema and restore it to the new database.
Then you can drop the broken database and rename the new copy, and you have got the information_schema back.
